# Grub wont load. cant boot either OS

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I'll start by saying I'm not the very tech savvy, so I'll really need help with this!
Problem: I cannot load either my Ubuntu OS OR my Windows 8. when i start my computer, a few lines run saying "failed to load grub" along with other things i couldnt really identify. Let me explain further:
Yesterday I had Installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP Laptop to run alongside Windows 8
The initial install went smooth but I encountered a problem: When I started up my computer, it would only load windows 8. After Looking around I saw i needed to run something called boot-repair within a liveusb/dvd of the Ubuntu installer. After running  this program i was told i could restart my computer. after doing so, My problem appeared. Now all i can do  with my computer is use the live usb i created. Theres alot more to it, but thats the basic what happened. I'd very much appreciate help, I'm kind of scared!
Also, the boot-repair gave me a link, im guessing its the results of the repair? idk, I'll put it here http://paste.ubuntu.com/5662277/

Comment: It would help, significantly, if you could post the "other things [you] couldnt really identify."  While it may look like gibberish, it could prove useful to those of us who may be able to help.

Don't fret yet... there's a plethora of people who have previously had GRUB loading issues (including myself) that were eventually resolved.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out all the SecureBoot and UEFI settings? you can read trough [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)